# Keeping cscope db updated

Tags: cscope

I work on a large project with many contributors and everyday I usually have to regenerate to keep this up to date and that is very time consuming.

Do any of you have any unique solutions to help with this so that it doesn't stop my workflow?

Answer (score 2):

I use a shell function to perform `git checkout`.  (I call it `gco`.)

This function performs some index updating, if the checkout succeeds.  (In my case I am interested in updating my `cindex`, while you want to update your `cscope`.)

```
gco() {
    git checkout "$@"
    local ret_status="$?"
    if [ "$ret_status" = 0 ] && [ -n "$POST_GIT_CHECKOUT" ]
    then "$POST_GIT_CHECKOUT" "$@"
    fi
    return "$ret_status"
}

POST_GIT_CHECKOUT=update_cindex     # update_cindex is another shell function!
```

You can see it [in context here](https://github.com/joeytwiddle/rc_files/blob/0b83ca33a222bbfb4abc0393abc7bd90d247ea2a/j/config/auto.sh/git_aliases#L249).  (In the end I found I could run `cindex` in the background, and with `ionice`, so it didn't delay my progress.)

Other users may want to trigger these kind of updates after a `git pull` or an `svn update`.